# google_new_transError: 429 (Too Many Requests) from TTS API. Probable cause: Unknown, Google Translate API

Tags: python, api, analytics, google-translate

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator

t= translator.translate('Bakrya vikne ahe', lang_tgt='mr') 


Output:
google_new_transError: 429 (Too Many Requests) from TTS API. Probable cause: Unknown
```

I am getting this error eventhough it is just a single line of text

Comment: You have used the API too often. There's a limit of free usage. Wait some time for the block to release.

Comment: @KlausD. Cool Thanks for the help!